# F11 key doesn't work for "Show launchpad", no idea why

Tags: keyboard, mission-control, launchpad

I am trying to set <kbd>F11</kbd> as a key for opening Launchpad (I have a Mac with Magic Keyboard, and I never use F11 and F12 (I use F1-F10 for Unix utilities) - so I want to map one for Launchpad and another for mission control).

The problem is that it just never registers (nothing happens after I press it).

Here are my settings:
I have set <kbd>F11</kbd> to "Show Launchpad" action, and there are no conflicts:

[image]

I have set F keys as standard function keys:

[image]

F11 is disabled in Mission control, only F12 is set there.

[image]

Any idea why F11 doesn't do anything for me?

EDIT: It might be a weird hackintosh problem:

1. I tested this on my Macbook - it works there on both built-in keyboard and Magic Keyboard 2.
2. But when I connect the same Magic keyboard to my Hackintosh, only F12 key triggers something, but F11 doesn't. F11 works, though, I can press it to map the action to F11 in Keyboard settings, but then the created shortcut doesn't do anything.

Comment: The alternate (or primary depending on how configured) function of F11 should be "Volume Down." When you press it, does it work?

Comment: @Allan I have 'Use F1 ... as a standard function keys' turned on, and F12 works normally, it's just F11 that refuses to be mapped.